# Establish positive definiteness of a term

Tags: positive-definite, positive-semidefinite

Consider the following scalar term
$$
T(x):=x^\top Qx,
$$
with $x\in\mathbb{R}^2$, $x\neq 0$ and
$$
Q:=\begin{bmatrix}-b\\a
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}-b+k_1&a+k_2
\end{bmatrix}
\in\mathbb{R}^{2\times 2},$$

with fixed $a,b\in\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$, free $k_1,k_2\in\mathbb{R}$.

If $k_1=k_2=0$, it can be seen that $\mathrm{rank}(Q)=1$, since it corresponds to the outer product of the vector $\begin{bmatrix}-b\\a\end{bmatrix}$. Hence $Q$ has a positive and a zero eigenvalue, which implies that $T(x)$ is not (strictly) positive definite.

The question is now the following: does exist a pair $(k_1,k_2)$ (it can be dependent from $a,b$ if necessary) such that the term $T(x)$ is (strictly) positive definite? If not, can anyone provide a proof for non-existence?

**EDITED**

I've been proceeding by splitting the $Q$ in the symmetric and skew-symmetric parts $Q=Q_{sym}+Q_{skew}$
\begin{align}
Q_{sym}:=&\begin{bmatrix}b^2-bk_1&-ab+\frac{ak_1-bk_2}{2}\\
-ab+\frac{ak_1-bk_2}{2}&a^2+ak_2
\end{bmatrix}\\
Q_{skew}:=&\begin{bmatrix}0&-\frac{ak_1+bk_2}{2}\\
\frac{ak_1+bk_2}{2}&0\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}

Now, by using the fact that $x^\top Q_{skew}x=0$, the term reduces to
$$
T(x)=x^\top Q_{sym}x,
$$
where $Q_{sym}$ has rank 2.

Answer (score 1):

It cannot be strictly positive definite.

$Q$ is the product of two  matrices that are at most rank $1$, hence the rank of $Q$ has to be less than or equal to $1$.

Note that if $Q=AB$ then $rank(Q) \leq \min(rank(A),rank(B)) \leq 1$, hence $nullity(Q) \geq 1$.

We can find $x \neq 0$ such that $Qx=0$ and hence $x^TQx=0$.

Edit:

A simpler proof:

if $a=b=0$, clearly $Q=0$.

Otherwise, choose $x = \begin{bmatrix} a \\ b\end{bmatrix}$

Comment: Could you please have a look at the edited text?

Comment: To understand what is going on, we can substitute in $a=b=k_1=k_2=1$ and our resulting matrix is $\begin{bmatrix} 0 & -2 \\ 0 & 2\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ -1 & 2\end{bmatrix}  + \begin{bmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0\end{bmatrix} $. $x^TQ_{skew}x$ is indeed 0 and $Q_{sym}$ in fact is rank $2$. However, notice that $Q_{sym}$ is indefinite. one of the eigenvalue is positive and one of the eigenvalue is negative.

Comment: notice that even though $Q_{sym}x \neq 0$, it is still possible to have $x^TQ_{sym}x=0$. For example, you can play with matrix $Q_{sym}=diag(1,-1)$ to find such $x$.

Comment: I understand your example. However I don't see how by considering directly the term 

$T(x)=x^\top Q_{sym}x$ 

you can make conclusions on the fact that the term cannot be positive definite.

A last point is the following. Is that possible to generalize that for non-zero $k_1,k_2$, the term T has always two eigenvalues of different sign? There's a proof for this? Txs for your help!

Comment: I have shown that $\exists x \neq 0$, $x^TQx=0$, Since $Q=Q_{sym}+Q_{skew}$ , we have $x^T(Q_{sym}+Q_{skew})x=0$. From $x^TQ_{skew}x=0$, we can conclude that using the same $x$, $x^TQ_{sym}x=0$. This implies that $Q_{sym}$ is not positive definite or negative definite. Hence $Q_{sym}$ is either singular or indefinite.

Comment: Alternatively, show that $\begin{bmatrix} a & b \end{bmatrix} Q_{sym} \begin{bmatrix} a \\ b \end{bmatrix} =0$